# Phalcon View not found exception

Tags: phalcon

I have recently upgraded phalcon from 2.0.10 to 3.1.2 and PHP to version 7. Everything worked well before but seems its now broken after the upgrade

In `index.php`, i have set the partial directory like this-

```
 $di->set('partials', function() {
     $partials = new View();
     $partials->setPartialsDir('../apps/common/views/');
     return $partials;
 });
```

And in `index.phtml`, the partial is called like this

```
$this->partials->partial("header");
```

`header.phtml` exist in `../apps/common/views` directory.

When I run the site, it gives following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Phalcon\Mvc\View\Exception: View
>   '../apps/common/views/header' was not found in any of the views
>   directory in
>   D:\server\www\booktickets.com\frontend\apps\modules\books\views\index.phtml

The partial `header.phtml` is partial directory. Can anybody shed light on this??

Comment: Try setting the partials directory to an absolute path.  If you're using the default Volt engine, you can simply use `{{ partial() }}` instead of setting up something new in the DI & calling raw PHP code in your view.  See: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/volt.html#view-integration

Comment: @Pickle, Unfortunately I m not using Volt

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution

I have to changed my code to -

```
$di->set('partials', function() {
    $partials = new View();
    $partials->setViewsDir('../apps/common/views'); // absolute path to views dir
    $partials->setPartialsDir('./'); // relative path to partials dir within
    return $partials;
 });
```

I got an answer from offical phalcon forum. [Here](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/16273/partial-not-found-in-any-of-the-views-directory-exception) is the link